# Return key according to value of python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary say

```
d = {"david":30, "vivian":40, "tom":20,"echo":40}
```

My goal is:

1. To return the key with the largest value.
2. In case there is a tie in the value, the key with the shortest length (number of letters) will be prioritized. So, in this case, "echo" will be returned.

I can achieve first goal with:

```
max_key = max(d, key=d.get)
```

How can I achieve the second goal?

Comment: `max(d, key=lambda x: (d[x], -len(x)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max()` orders the items by the value returned by the `key` argument, so the *key* here is to figure out a way to order the shorter dictionary keys first. You can do this by returning a tuple from the `key` function, which contains the value and the length of the dictionary key.

```
max_key = max(d, key=lambda k: (d[k], -len(k)))
# 'echo'
```

Since you're using the `max` function and you want the *smallest* length selected, you have to use `-len(k)` .

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more concise way to do this but this seems to work:

```
d = {"david":30, "vivian":40, "tom":20,"echo":40}

print(sorted([(v, k) for k, v in d.items()], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[1])))[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
(40, 'echo')
```